# How to change the JSON output format in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, nsmutablearray

Hi Im totally new to iOS Development, Please help me to sort out this issue

I could able to retrieve the JSON values in the below format: and also i have attached the code which I used to retrieve the json output

My Code:

```
 NSData *cityData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];


NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

        __block NSDictionary *json;
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                                   json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                          options:0
                                                                            error:nil];
                                   NSLog(@"Async JSON: %@", json);
                               }];
```

This is how i got the output :

```
Async JSON: (
        {
        "job_code" = SRTCN01121;
        "job_id" = 1121;
    },
        {
        "job_code" = SRTCN01126;
        "job_id" = 1126;
    }
)
```

But this is not what i need, I need the json output format something like below:

```
Async JSON: (
            (
            SRTCN01121,
             1121
        ),
            (
            SRTCN01126,
            1126
        )
    )
```

Please help me to sort out this issue

Comment: everything is fine you can directly access the value using key, no need to retrieve , its my suggestion

Comment: @Tela: So you simply want the values, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can have  a model class where you can store the values for each set of your data

```
@interface Job : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger jobID;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *jobCode;
@end
```

Now here is piece of code which can be used to parse the JSON data. Considering you have `NSDictionary` json which has the JSON response

> **NOTE**: () in the JSON response says array whereas {} says dictionary.
>
> You have nested dictionaries in your response.

```
- (NSArray *)parseResponse:(NSDictionary *)jsonResponse
{
    NSMutableArray *responseArray = [NSMutableArray array];

   for (NSDictionary *dictionary in jsonResponse) 
   {
        Job *job = [[Job alloc] init];
        job.jobID = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"job_id"] integerValue];
        job.jobCode = [dictionary valueForKey:@"job_code"]; 

        [responseArray addObject:job];
    }

    return [responseArray copy];
}
```

Following is the way you can access your data from the array.

```
- (void)printResponse:(NSArray *)array
{
    for(Job *job in array)
    {
        NSLog(@"Code : %@, ID : %ld", job.jobCode, job.jobID);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.